# javascript increase id for every click

Tags: javascript

i want to increase the id for every click. I spent 2 hours but somehow i couldnt manage to do it.

```js
var app = document.getElementById('app');
var circle = document.querySelector('.mny-circle');
var item = document.querySelector('.mny-item');
var button = document.querySelector('.mny-btn');
var id = 0;

var UIcontroller = function() {
  var newItem = '<div id="item-%id%" class="mny-item">Deneme</div>';
  var addItem = newItem.replace('%id%', id);
  var clickbtn = function() {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      circle.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', addItem);
    });
    id++;
  }
  clickbtn();
}

UIcontroller();
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning mny-btn">Click</button>
  <div class="mny-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `clickbtn()` firing?

Comment: Put it in your question.  It's not a comment.

Comment: When using the snippet feature, make sure to put all your code in one snippet, not several like you had it :)

Comment: because you replace the id before the event function, not in it `circle.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newItem.replace('%id%', id++));`

Comment: check the answer i have posted.

Comment: Thank you @SamaBalaYam it worked as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are.

```js
var app = document.getElementById('app');
var circle = document.querySelector('.mny-circle');
var item = document.querySelector('.mny-item');
var button = document.querySelector('.mny-btn');


var UIcontroller = function() {
  var id = 0;
  var newItem = '<div id="item-%id%" class="mny-item">Deneme</div>';

  var clickbtn = function() {

    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      
      circle.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newItem.replace('%id%', id));
      id++;
    });

  }
  clickbtn();
}

UIcontroller();
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning mny-btn">Click</button>
  <div class="mny-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

should be like this :

```
 button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var addItem = newItem.replace('%id%', id);
  circle.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', addItem);
  id++;
});
```

you need to increment id in the click event.